# Delphi Indy 10 Smtp Error "Unable to authenticate at present"

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy10

I am using this piece of code to mail a test message from delphi indy.
I have a TidSMTP,TIdMessage and IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

In the belowe code if i set it up to use gmail with ssl it works fine, but as soon as i replace my the server details with my cpanel mail server detials it does not work error:

> " unable to authenticate at present".

I used same details I would use to setup my account in outlook 2007. Here is the code

IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL details.

```
method := sslvsslv3
mode := sslmUnassigned

//rest default values

procedure Tfrmnotification.btnSendClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdMsg : TIdMessage;
begin

begin
  IdMsg := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
  try
    with TIdSMTP.Create(nil) do
    try
     // UserName := 'something@gmail.com';
     // Password := 'pass';
     // Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
     // IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
     // Port := 587;
      UserName := 'something@sasra.co.za';
      Password := 'password';
      Host := 'outgoing server detials';// same as outlooks
      IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
      Port := 465;// this is correct port
      UseTLS:=  utUseExplicitTLS;


      IdMsg.Body.Add('test');
      IdMsg.Recipients.emailAddresses := 'something@gmail.com';
      IdMsg.Subject := 'test';
      IdMsg.From.Address := 'something@sasra.co.za';
      IdMsg.From.Name := 'john';


      Connect;
      Send(IdMsg);
      Disconnect;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdMsg.free;
  end;
  showmessage('done');
end;
```

Any help would be appricated.

Comment: So the server you're communicating with is an exchange server? So the problem is making an SSL connection to Exchange? Does it work when you try it with Mozilla Thunderbird Email client?  If it doesn't work with that, why are you trying to write code for something that might not be configured to work properly on the server end?

Comment: Hey Warren P. Thanks for your reply. The server is not an exchange server. My assumption is that if I can send mails from Microsoft office 2007, I should be able to do the same with my delphi code. I am hoping that I just missed something in my code or component atributes.

Comment: Well then, try it in some OTHER email program than Exchange, and figure out what authentication settings you need there, and that might tell you what to do. TLS etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port 465 is used for SMTP over implicit SSL. You have set UseTLS to utUseExplicitTLS. The correct value should (most likely) be utUseImplicitTLS.

Comment: If you want to use explicit TLS instead, set the `Port` to 587, or leave it as 25 (setting the `UseTLS` property will update the `Port` for you if it contains its default value).

Comment: Correct, and it is obviously very important to pay attention to the connection detail the server owner gives you. If the server doesn't listen on port 465 or port 587, there is obviously no point try to connect on those ports.

Comment: The reason I mention it is because setting the `UseTLS` property may or may not implicitally update the `Port` property before you connect, depending on what the Port property was previously set to. I have seen cases where people did pay attention to that fact and ended up connecting to a different port than they are expecting.